# How to hide google map markers swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I want to hide the marker after the zoom level reach 17, someone suggested  I use clear method, but the issue with it that I have different marker that will show after some event so clear is not going to work any idea how can I made this possible?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know there are no definite references to hiding markers, but you can manipulate marker data displayed on the map #CMIIW

as an example

```
var markers: [GMSMarker] = []
var tempMarker: [GMSMarker] = []

if zoom == 17 {
   // TODO: Create tempMarker filter from markers
} else {
   // TODO: Create tempMarker filter from markers
}

// TODO:
// mapView.clear()
// Mapview show markers from tempMarker
```

[iOS Swift Google Maps SDK showing markers at specific zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180112/ios-swift-google-maps-sdk-showing-markers-at-specific-zoom-level/51202906#51202906)

Answer (score 0):

- To remove a specific marker

  myMarker.map = nil

Comment: like I said before I dont want to remove just hide

Answer (score 0):

//To delete

marker.map = nil

//to hide

marker.opacity = 0.0